# Open API generator - two generations, order is not same

Tags: ballerina, ballerina-swan-lake

once I generate OpenAPI definition pointing to same service, the order API resources and schema entries added is not same. This makes it is impossible to see a diff between the two.

In practical scenarios, there are situations where we need to see what is added/removed from the OpenAPI.

```
- generate openAPI for a service
- make some modifications 
- generate again 
- try to see the diff between the two OpenAPIs
```

Another issue found was When enum is defined in a different module other than the module where service.bal file is, enum is not added to OpenAPI generated.

See Above description provided.